# flyway with spring boot and gradle--org.flywaydb.core.Flyway: method <init>()V not found

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, flyway, nosuchmethoderror

I have a spring boot project with gradle and using postgres db. I want to test by using flyway for database migrations. I am facing below error. My build.gradle and application.properties are also given below. Please help me with this error. I believe this is something to do with set up but not the actual code.

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.flywaydb.core.Flyway: method <init>()V not found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1072) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1082) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:123) ~[spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:666) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:353) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:300) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1082) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1071) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at com.ford.mach1mldb.AccessingDataRestApplication.main(AccessingDataRestApplication.java:10) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.flywaydb.core.Flyway: method <init>()V not found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.flywaydb.core.Flyway: method <init>()V not found
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$SpringBootFlyway.<init>(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:184) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$SpringBootFlyway.<init>(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:184) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.flyway(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:130) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1b5373a9.CGLIB$flyway$0(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1b5373a9$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b74dfec1.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1b5373a9.flyway(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.22.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
         url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
      }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")

    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {

    compile( 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest' )
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile files('./lib/postgresql-42.2.8.jar') 
    compile group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core', version: '6.0.1'
    compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.0.Final'   
    compile group: 'org.springframework.ws', name: 'spring-ws-support'
    compile('org.springframework:spring-context-support')
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.5"
    compile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp', name: 'okhttp', version: '2.7.5' 
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-dependencies:1.4.1.RELEASE"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Dalston.SR5"
    }
}
```

Application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

#postgress
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://xxx/xxx
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect


flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I also upgrade my version of the flyway from 5.2.4 to 7.0.0 and catch the same error.

To resolve this issue I downgrade the flyway version to 6.5.0 and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Try another version of flyway (older) or remove version if it possible in Gradle (It helps for me with maven).